# Google search - translate links over actual links

Tags: google-search, firefox

I'm using Firefox on Arch Linux, and the Google results are looking weird, with some text over the title to the pages' links:

[image]

The offending text is a link to Google's translated version of the page.

Searching on Google for the issue, the best I could find was some former Mozilla exec stating that Google does that sometimes to make people move to Chrome:

https://www.zdnet.com/article/former-mozilla-exec-google-has-sabotaged-firefox-for-years/

Anyone else seeing this issue?  I'm finding it hard to explain it in English, perhaps a better wording of the issue will find some matches.

I don't think I'm changing my default search engine to DuckDuckGo, but I'm definitely not moving to Chrome :p

Comment: Maybe some Firefox add-ons that comes into conflict because of some custom CSS ? More, if you can tell what's the problem you can put your custom CSS easily. (For sure Google has an history of shady business practice. Overall i prefer DeepL for traduction purpose.)

Comment: @pjmg, it's not an add-on thing, as I have none.  Regarding the translation, I don't even want it, but Google shows it on the search results, anyway.  But I'll see if there's any configurations to remove that.

Comment: Maybe you need to set the same language within Firefox, Archlinux and Google.     Or if you want english result to use a vpn with an US IP. Or use /ncr to stop redirect (I.E. https://www.google.it/ncr for italian version, .es/ncr for spain, .co.uk/ncr for england, etc..). Can you share the url or the **lang=** in the html tag in the view-source ? I'm out of ideas ! :)

Comment: @pjmg, thanks for your ideas, but I think you're looking at this from the wrong angle.  The problem is not on language or translation; the problem looks more like some bad CSS - there is text over other text, and I cannot properly read some of the links because of that.  It just happens to be a link to the translation service, but that's not the core of the problem.  In any case, here's the `html` tag: `<html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchResultsPage" lang="pt-BR">`

Comment: By the way, I searched for a configuration to disable the translation links, but found none on the Google configurations